# Моя задача вывести все простые числа от firstNumber до n

Tags: javascript, простые-числа

```js
let firstNumber = prompt("Введи первое число", 2);
let n = prompt("Введи n:", 10);


for (let i = firstNumber; i <= n; i++) {
  if ((i <= 1) || (n < 2)) {
    i = prompt("Введи первое число", 2);
    n = prompt("Введи n:", 10);
  } else {
    сontinue;
  }

  for (let j = 2; j < n; j++) {

    if ((i % j) === 0) {
      console.log(i);
      document.write(i + "<br/>");
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

Подскажите в чём у меня ошибка? Почему не срабатывает код?

Comment: Ты _всегда_ упираешься в первый `сontinue`

Comment: На что его можно было бы изменить?

Comment: это ведь проверка введённых данных, её нужно вообще вынести из цикла

Comment: Но так тоже не срабатывает:
let firstNumber = prompt ("Введи первое число", 2);
let n = prompt ("Введи n:", 10);

if ((firstNumber <= 1) || (n < 2)){
  firstNumber = prompt ("Введи первое число", 2);
  n = prompt ("Введи n:", 10);
} else{
  for (let i = firstNumber; i <= n; i++){

    for (let j = 2; j < n; j++) {

      if ((i % j) === 0){
         document.write (i + "<br/>");
      }else{
        continue;
      }

    }

  }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, нужно, как правильно сказано в комментариях, вынести проверку введенных значений за цикл.
Во-вторых, во втором цикле, в условии for, стоит поменять n на i. Тогда этот цикл будет перебирать, как и нужно, числа от 2 до текущего числа из заданного интервала.
В-третьих, у вас получилось так, что число посчитается простым и выведется каждый раз, когда нацело поделится на любое число до себя.
Самый простой вариант - ввести перед внутренним циклом специальную булевую переменную, которая по умолчанию будет true. Если хоть раз условие, которое дано в вашем втором цикле, проходит, нужно выдать этой переменной false и выйти из цикла (чисто ради производительности, в дальнейших действиях нет смысла, число точно не простое).
А после этого вложенного цикла - проверка той переменной. Если она осталась true, то число простое и его можно вывести, в противном случае ничего делать с ним не надо.
У меня понятно получилось объяснить?)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Понятно обьяснили!